# Not able to configure adojob store Error: There is no metadata information for provider 'MySql-51', Could not Initialize DataSource: myDS

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-4.5, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have .net 4.5.2 application with quartz.net 3.0.4. I am trying to use adojobstore with mysql as database
My configuration is

```
<add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="DBScheduler" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="100" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="2" />
<add key="quartz.scheduler.dbFailureRetryInterval" value="6000000000" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="600000" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="myDS" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString" value="Server=localhost;Port=3306;database=quartznet;Uid=root;pwd=root;allow user variables=true;CharSet=utf8;" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider" value="MySql-51" />
```

I am always getting error
Could not Initialize DataSource: myDS
Inner Exception: There is no metadata information for provider 'MySql-51'
Parameter name: providerName

Please help me identify the problem

I have even tried `<add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider" value="MySql" />`

Comment: Why this is marked negative. I am 100% sure that other might also face this problem and this post will be helpful. Stackoverflow needed to introduce a mandatory comment for negative marking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/601) (please indicate that you are cross-posting when asking questions), the documentation was not up to date.

[Documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/job-stores.html) has been updated to not have the version postfix for the providers. So you should replace "Mysql-51" with "MySql".

Comment: Thanks a lot Marko

Comment: The reference to the version postfix is still there in 2.x docs, which may cause confusion https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/job-stores.html#ado-net-job-store-adojobstore

Comment: The postfix should be valid for the 2.x version.